# Can you add reactive values to a custom store

Tags: svelte

If in your store you have  an object

```
[{
amount: 0, 
fee: 5, 
}]
```

but you have multiple components that need a total value:

do I have to add the following to each component, I want to use the total value

```
$: total = $store.amount + $store.fee
```

or is there is a way to write reactive equations in the store

This is the properly example of the store

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

let donation = {
    amount: 50, 
        fee: 10,
    continue: false,
    
    
};

const createStore = () => {
    const { update, subscribe, set } = writable(donation);

    return {
        subscribe,
        update,
        set,
        handleContinue: () =>
            update((current) => {
                current.continue = true;
                return current;
            }),
    };
};

export const donationCheckoutStore = createStore();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a derived store for this if you want

```js
export const donationsTotal = derived(
  donationCheckoutStore, 
  $store => $store.amount + $store.fee
);
```

This is a readable store (so no `.set` or `.update` methods) that will automatically update when it's base changes. You would use it like any other store:

```html
<span>Total: {$donationsTotal}</span>
```

Comment: Is the way the derived equation made diffs for a regular store vs a custom store? In assuming for a larger project its better to start using and understanding custom storea better

Comment: Also is there anyway that i can connect with you. Id love have a session to understand this properly. I dont mind paying.

Comment: derived stores are the same for regular and custom stores

Comment: okay i tested it and i understand it a little more. 

One final question. 

is there anyway to introduce if statements into the derived store example 
```
export const donationsTotal = derived(
 donationCheckoutStore,
 ($store) => 
 
 if($store.continue){
  $store.donatedAmount + 50
 }
 else {
  $store.donatedAmount + 50

 }
);```

Comment: You can put as much code in there as you want, as long as it returns a value, you are good to go

Comment: oh my god, it worked after i played around with it!!! you are a blessing stephane. THANK YOU~~!!